# GeoServer printing module - Error while download PDF

Tags: geoserver, mapfish-print

I installed Geonode and Geoserver perfectly. And I configured nginx proxy to run on https

So far it worked:

The print module configuration file in GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/printing/config.yaml is created and I can see access the `https://mydomainname/geoserver/pdf/info.json`

And I can see printURL: `https://mydomainname/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf` and createURL: `https://mydomainname/geoserver/pdf/create.json` Parameters in info.json

Here is my config.yaml

```
#===========================================================================
# allowed DPIs
#===========================================================================
dpis:
  - 96
  - 150
  - 300

#===========================================================================
# the allowed scales
#===========================================================================
scales:
  - 0.35
  - 0.7
  - 1.5
  - 3.5
  - 7.0
  - 15.0
  - 35.0
  - 70.0
  - 150.0
  - 273.0
  - 546.0
  - 1093.0
  - 2187.5
  - 4375.0
  - 8750.0
  - 17500.0
  - 35000.0
  - 70000.0
  - 138000.0
  - 273437.5
  - 546875.0
  - 1093750.0
  - 2187500.0
  - 4375000.0
  - 8750000.0
  - 17500000.0
  - 35000000.0
  - 70000000.0
  - 140000000.0
  - 280000000.0

outputFilename: 'GeoNode-Map-${date}.pdf'
#== ms2 ===== 
disableScaleLocking: true
#======
brokenUrlPlaceholder: 'default'
# brokenUrlPlaceholder: 'throw'

proxyBaseUrl: https://mydomainname/geoserver/pdf
connectionTimeout: 2000
socketTimeout: 2000

#===========================================================================
# the list of allowed ips
#===========================================================================
hosts:
  - !ipMatch
    ip: 127.0.0.1
  - !localMatch
    dummy: true
  - !acceptAll
    dummy: true
  - !dnsMatch
    host: mydomainname
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: localhost
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: labs.metacarta.com
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: terraservice.net
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: www.geocat.ch
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: otile1.mqcdn.com
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: otile2.mqcdn.com
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: otile3.mqcdn.com
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: otile4.mqcdn.com
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: otile5.mqcdn.com
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: a.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: b.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: c.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: d.tile.openstreetmap.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: a.tile.openstreetmap.fr
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: b.tile.openstreetmap.fr
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: c.tile.openstreetmap.fr
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: d.tile.openstreetmap.fr
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: en.unesco.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: en.unesco.org/tiles
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: en.unesco.org/tiles/geodata
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: api.mapbox.com
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9/tiles
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v9/tiles
    port: 80
```

Here is the NGINX Configuration:

```
server {

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name mydomainname;

  charset utf-8;

  etag on;
  expires $expires;
  proxy_read_timeout 600s;
  # set client body size to 2M #
  client_max_body_size 50000M;

  location / {
    etag off;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;
    include uwsgi_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    include proxy_params;
  }

  location /geoserver {
    proxy_pass http://geoserver_proxy;
    include proxy_params;
    etag off;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;
    include uwsgi_params;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

But when I generate the pdf the getURL parameter from create.json url comes with HTTP instead of HTTPS

`http://mydomainname/geoserver/pdf/18439792855979453446.pdf.printout`

Please help me to get the pdf URL with the HTTPS schema. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: did you add that url to the nginx configuration to be https?

Comment: Hello @IanTurton, yes I did as you can see above